# Total textbox value should not be zero using jquery

Tags: jquery

Im checking the textbox value should not accept zero.. its working if I give all 0's or a single 0. But, when I give value such as 00010, its also validating.. which it should not. I'm using indexOf to test the field value.

The total value of the textbox should not be 0.

here is my code

```
 function AlertSave() {
    var val = $('#txt').val().replace(/[\s\n\r]/g,"");
    if( val == 0 || val.indexOf("0") > -1){
        alert('should not be 0')
    }
 }
```

A simple fiddle

```
http://jsfiddle.net/h4JXs/4900/
```

Comment: I typed that number and it alerts *"should not be 0"*

Comment: @T J try to give as 010.. this is not a 0, right? its 10

Comment: When you give 00010 as input, it alerts 'should not be 0'. What is the problem? You don't want to alert it?

Comment: `val.indexOf("0")` means "is there 0 inside your string, somewhere..." ?

Comment: Use only `if(val == 0 && val!='')`.

Comment: @Thanasis, the total value of the textbox should not accept 0. I have edited the question. Plz check it

Comment: What do you mean by total value? e.g. total value of 00010 is 10?

Comment: @Thanasis, yes.. it should validate only if the total textbox value is 0.

Comment: The code I suggested above does this exactly. Replace `if( val == 0 || val.indexOf("0") > -1)` with `if(val == 0 && val!='')`. When I put 00010 and click the button it doesn't alrt anything and when I put 000 it alerts the message. It works fine for me. Test it and tell my what's wrong with it.

Comment: Thanasis,  can you plz put that in a fiddle.. because I'm using a phone now to test.. I will accept the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you need is this:

```
function AlertSave() {
   var val = $('#txt').val().replace(/[\s\n\r]/g,"");
      if( val == 0 && val!=''){
       alert('should not be 0')
      }
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h4JXs/4903/

Comment: Accepted. Kudos! Thanks Thanasis

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
$("#txt").on('input', function() {
    var this_element = $(this);
    if(this_element.val().indexOf("0") >= 0) {
        var newStr = this_element.val().substring(0, this_element.val().length-1);
        this_element.val(newStr);
    }
})
```

See updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/h4JXs/4902/

Comment: Saumya, its not even taking 0 as input.. this is not expected.

Comment: This code will neglect 0 if you try to input a 0 in the text box

Comment: No.. I can type 100, right? Im expecting the total textbox value should not be 0. for eg.. 000 is invalid, 010 is valid and 001 is valid.. because it has some value

Comment: You can simply do it as if(this_element.val() == 0) { alert('not allowed'); }

Comment: Thanks Saumya for your effort